# Force notebook fans to run at 100% all the time

Tags: windows-7, laptop, fan

RivaTuner doesn't detect my dedicated graphics chip (AMD 7470M) which seems to control the fans, so I can't force fan settings. SpeedFan is unable to display the RPM and has no effect, and my mainboard (SJV70 HR) is also unrecognized. It's an OEM machine where I don't have any BIOS options and I was unable to find a compatible unlocked BIOS I could flash.

So, is there a *software* solution for this? Not looking for general advice how to prevent overheating here, I just want my fans to run 100% all the time regardless of actual temperature, like they do on booting. Possible?

Comment: Its entirely possible it has fans that does not support  what you want.  The ability to adjust the speed of the fan requires a fan connector with a certain amount of pins.

Comment: No fan controls in CCC (under Performance -> OverDrive)? Try using the AMD Catalyst 13.4 drives.

Comment: So your laptop has a cooling fan, AND a dedicated fan for the GPU?  And you want only the GPU fan to run at 100%?  Or does this mysterious  make/model laptop only have one fan, and you want that one to run at 100%?  You say the BIOS has no options... Does your laptop have an AMD processor, or an INTEL processor?  Is there a Cool & Quiet option in the BIOS that you can disable?

Comment: The laptop only has two GPU fans, or at least no tools have been able to find any others. It's a Packard Bell EasyNote LS44HR-400GE, and as far as I can tell the mainboard is a Packard Bell SJV70 HR, CPU is Intel Pentium B960, and GPU is AMD Radeon HD 7470M. The BIOS seems to be tailored to this particular setup and practically doesn't let me edit anything except the boot sequence, so no Cool & Quiet option there (or overclocking settings for that matter).

Since it's an OEM machine I can't install the official AMD drivers, and the latest leshcat CCC doesn't give me any fan control options.

Comment: Well, any ideas?